# Render Razor View Page as string from WebApi Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-2.1

I have mock `cshtml` that looks like this:

```html
@model TaskManager.Models.ViewModels.ProjectRaportViewModel

@{
    var name = Model.Project.Name;

    <h3>@name</h3>
}
<br />
<4h>Hello World!</4h>
```

I want to return that view(or any) as `string` but as `html` rendered by `Razor` (so i think, razor will change `C#` things to `html` tags etc).

I have a `controller` that looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet("{projectId}")]
    public IActionResult GetRaportFromProject([FromRoute] int projectId)
    {
        var html = this.pdfService.RenderViewToHtml(projectId);
        return this.Content(html, "text/html", Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

And in `pdfService` i have this method:

```
    public string RenderViewToHtml(int projectId)
    {
        this.projectService.GetItem(projectId);

        var raportHtml = what to do next?                   
    }
```

My question is, how to render `cshtml` to `html` by `Razor` in service class and then return it as `string` from `WebApi` endpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use .Net Core, there is a NuGet package you can easily install: [RazorEngine.NetCore](https://github.com/fouadmess/RazorEngine)

The documentation is good but here is the short version:

Include the library:

```
    using RazorEngine;
    using RazorEngine.Templating;
```

Get your razor html

```
        string razorView= "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
```

If it's in a file you could use `File.ReadAllText`

```
        string razorView = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);
```

and compile:

```
string result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(razorView, "templateKey", null, null);
```

And if you want to inject some object, pass it in the 4th argument